# Calling reload data while scrolling on UIScrollView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

I am implementing a UIScrollView which behaves mostly like a UITableView, a bit more advanced with that.. but most of the API used are the same signature.. cellForRowAtIndexPath.. etc. First before people start storming why not just use a UITableView, let me just say that I can't. The reasons are fairly complex, but that is a decision been made.

The issue is now I am implementing infinite scrolling, basically when I scroll down and I am at 65% of the full contentHeight I am doing an async request to the backend to fetch more data and adding it to the data source and then calling reloadData. The issue is that if I am calling reloadData while the user is scrolling, it doesn't provide a very smooth scrolling experience. So what is the best way to tackle this? Also I noticed that reloadData basically refreshes the entire table view (in this case my scroll view). In my table view cell I am animating a UIImage to fade in. So when reloadData is called, the image that is already presented is being faded in again, which is kind of annoying.
How do I avoid such things?

Any tips and tricks?

Comment: Why would you duplicate Apple's efforts in designing your own `UITableView`? The `UITableView` class inherits from `UIScrollView`, so whatever you can do with a scroll view, you can do with `UITableView`.

Comment: I am doing smtg similar to UICollectionView in iOS 6 and I am supporting iOS 5, so I can't use UITableView. That's the shortest answer I can come up with right now why I am not using UITableView

Answer (score 3):

In case you're still working on this, check out [PSTCollectionView](https://github.com/steipete/PSTCollectionView). It works exactly like UICollection view but supports backwards of iOS 4.3.

Answer (score 0):

Its difficult to answer without knowing why you need to create a custom view similar to the tableview. If you have a developer account you might want to check the new iOS 6 view based on tableview. Not sure if I can talk more about it as it is under NDA.

For the UIImage fading, how about flagging each UIImage as displayed and then do a check when reloading the data or recalling the fade statement. Only fade the images that are not flagged as already presented?

Comment: I thought of that too, but that seems a bit hacky

Comment: hacky? Your re-creating a tableview anyway ;)

Answer (score 0):

In new iOS 6.0 there is new controllers call UIContainer view,its similar to UITableview but we can also set more then one column with that.

delegate methods for that controllers are almost same as in UITableview.you can use that controller if you have similar requirements.